# Windows Deployment Services Error When Approving Machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, deployment, wds

I'm using WDS/Server 2008 R2 to deploy Windows 7 in a small organization. I have WDS configured to respond to all PXE clients, but require administrator approval.

When I PXE-boot a client, it sees the WDS server and begins to boot, then pauses awaiting for the admin approval. On the WDS server, the machine shows up as 'pending approval'. Everything as you;d expect.

The problem comes when approving the client request. If I pick either 'Approve' or 'Name and Approve', then WDS gives an error "The parameter was not correct".

If I configure the server to respond and automatically accept all requests, then everything works.

I can't find anything in the Internet about this issue, so over to you guys.... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found this rather old question while searching for a solution to this myself.
For the record just in case someone else ends up here in the future:

The WDS server's computer account needs to be granted rights to create computer accounts in the AD.
If you haven't specified a specific target OU in your WDS configuration - this would be the domain default computers OU.

The rights needed are listed in the task named "Prestage a computer" on this page:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754005(WS.10).aspx